# in vb.net, how to spawn a thread that has a Byref parameter?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

How can do I spawn a thread that has a ByRef parameter?
I want to check the message that is set in the subroutine.

Also, does the tread automatically stop when DoWork method ends?

I have:

```
    Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf DoWork(strMessage))
    thread.Start()

    Public Sub DoWork(ByRef strMessage As String)

       DBFunc.OpenDB()

       Try
           With DBFunc.objCmd
               .CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
               .CommandText = "ProcessBandwidthLogCalculated"
               .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
        Catch sqlex As SqlException
             strMessage = sqlex.Message
        Catch ex As Exception
             strMessage = ex.Message
        Finally
            ' Close database.
            DBFunc.CloseDB()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, when do you plan to use the returned value?  You of course have to wait until the thread is completed, that tends to defeat the point of using a thread rather badly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. ByRef isn't meant to be used across threads. You need to pass back the results using some other method.

Consider looking into Async/Await.

Comment: I don't want to use Async/Await as the DoWork method is called in a polling method (a timer). I don't want to hold up that timer. Can i just define the DoWork() method without the strMessage ByRef variable and instead set a global variable in that method and and just check it after the thread completes? Also, does the thread automatically stop when DoWork method ends?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Assigning a value to a reference variable is an "atomic" operation and thus thread safe by itself.

Comment: Yes, threads are automatically destroyed at the end of their function. (Which is why it is cheaper to use the thread pool than to create your own threads.)